# how use this php code in java desktop app

Tags: java, php

i have this simple php code and want to use this code in a java  app
in this way that the user enter the id in java console and check the Status of that id then show that to user

should i change this code to java code??
and how? plz help me

```
<?php
// www.webmn.net
function yahoo($id){
$url = 'http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=';
$data = file_get_contents($url . $id);
if (trim(strtolower(strip_tags($data))) != 'user not specified.') {
return (strlen($data) == 140) ? 'online' : 'offline';
} else {
return trim(strip_tags($data));
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a PHP server to run your php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put  php file in your sever , and then send a post request to it from your java app using this function

`public static String httpPost(String urlStr, String[] paramName,
            String[] paramVal) throws Exception {
              URL url = new URL(urlStr);
              HttpURLConnection conn =
                  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
              conn.setDoOutput(true);
              conn.setDoInput(true);
              conn.setUseCaches(false);
              conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
              conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

```
          // Create the form content
          OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
          Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
          for (int i = 0; i < paramName.length; i++) {
            writer.write(paramName[i]);
            writer.write("=");
            writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(paramVal[i], "UTF-8"));
            writer.write("&");
          }
          writer.close();
          out.close();

          if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
          }

          // Buffer the result into a string
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          String line;
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
          }
          rd.close();

          conn.disconnect();
          return sb.toString();
        }
```

Comment: can you explain about `String urlStr,String[] paramName,
            String[] paramVal`   what are these?

Comment: paramName is a table of parameters names  and 
paramVal  is a table of parameters values

Answer (score 1):

this code is about ajax request.

1, you can use HTTPclient to rewrite the PHP code.

2, download a PHP server, like resin:

```
http://www.caucho.com/resin-application-server/
```

Then, run the PHP-server with java(by a cmd.bat file), your write a Java-HTTPclient to visit this PHP page to get result.

Good luck.